# Change bridge vlan protocol from 802.1q to 802.1ad and packets start dropping

Tags: linux, vlan, tagging

I have a bridge interface (`swbridge`) with `vlan_protocol=802.1q`. Sending tagged frame to it. I can see ARP request in Wireshark Successfully (ping request from another device), but when changing `vlan_protocol` to `802.1ad` I can no longer see packets in Wireshark.

I've changed the bridge vlan protocol with this command:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "0x88a8" > /sys/class/net/swbridge/bridge/vlan_protocol'
```

```
# ip -d -j -p link show swbridge

...
                "vlan_filtering": 1,
                "vlan_protocol": "802.1ad",
...
```

```
# uname -a
Linux 5.15.71 ...
```

```
# bridge vlan
port              vlan-id  
port2             10
swbridge          10
```

What I am trying to do is adding a double vlan tag to incoming packets, but I've stuck in this step.

#### Edit

This setup may not be practical, but it is what I want. I want to see QinQ packet (802.1AD) on Client's port2:

[image]

This setup is tested successfully on GNS3.

Cisco device configs:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/25
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!         
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/26
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10
 switchport mode trunk
!
```

MySwitch vlan configs (before I go through why I get no packet):

```
# bridge vlan
port1             11 PVID Egress Untagged
port2             1 PVID Egress Untagged
                  11
swbridge          1
                  11
```

As you see we have a bridge (swbridge) that all ports are slave to.

I've created a vlan int (with following code), but it didn't work too until I finally found that swbridge with `vlan_protocol` `802.1ad` din't work at all (no packet goes through it).

```
ip link add link port1 name port1.11 type vlan proto 802.1ad id 11
```

And also note that I think required modules is present:

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
8021q                  28672  0
...
```

Comment: @A.B The client initiates the ping request on Port1. We get ARP requests on MySwitch's port1, which are tagged vlan 10. Now on MySwitch, we want to add another tag (vlan 11). "Also, obviously, you did more commands than just changing the mode." I have a problem with the setup in the first place, so I tried to break it down and reached a state that just changing `vlan_protocol` makes the ARP requests drop (or whatever it's called).

Comment: Never mind. Got it port1. so client -> client-port1 -> (access) cisco -> (trunk) -> 802.1q port1 ->  mySwitch -> QinQ port 2 -> QinQ client-port2

Answer (score 0):

A Linux bridge with `vlan_filtering=1` supports tagging/untagging a single layer of VLAN. That means, a 802.1AD (aka QinQ with the implied meaning that there's an other stacked 802.1Q VLAN layer inside) VLAN-aware bridge should be expected to see on its ports either 802.1Q frames (access port) or 802.1AD frames (trunk port), So they can get properly handled as QinQ.

When needed, anything not covered by this single bridge can be done by using either an other stacked (VLAN-aware) bridge or a VLAN interface. But no VLAN interface is needed in this setup since the Cisco switch already added the first layer of VLAN tag (802.1Q VID 10).

---

From comment, the experiment is as follow:

```
client - port1 (IP/ARP) --> 
--> access-port - cisco (internal tagging) - trunk-port (802.1q vid 10) --> 
    --> port1 (access) - swbridge (internal tagging) - port2 (trunk, 802.1ad vid 11 before 802.1q vid 10) -->
        --> port2 - client
```

I'm not sure where the setup doesn't work by OP, but setup for *MySwitch* below done from scratch (assuming there are two Ethernet interfaces named *port1* and *port2* matching OP's description) works when reproducing the setup.

Note that I don't allow anything on the bridge self interface, only on its ports: captures done on *MySwitch* should be done on *port1* or *port2*, not on *swbridge* (though capture in promiscuous mode should work).

```bash
# start over
ip link del dev swbridge
ip addr flush dev port1
ip addr flush dev port2

# all at once: VLAN filtering, 802.1AD and
# no VLAN enabled by default (not even VLAN 1), so no VLAN to delete later
ip link add name swbridge type bridge vlan_filtering 1 vlan_protocol 802.1ad vlan_default_pvid 0

ip link set dev port1 master swbridge up
ip link set dev port2 master swbridge up

bridge vlan add vid 11 dev port1 pvid untagged
bridge vlan add vid 11 dev port2

ip link set dev swbridge up
```

Now an ARP or IP packet sent from client on its *port1* receives a 802.1Q tag by the Cisco and over it a 802.1AD tag by *MySwitch* and is thus received as QinQ on client's port2.

There is no VLAN interface involved here, none was created. If a VLAN interface exists on *MySwitch* it should be deleted.

Note: the bridge's `vlan_protocol` value can be changed whenever needed (using `/sys/class/net/swbridge/bridge/vlan_protocol` or `ip link set dev swbridge type bridge vlan_protocol ...`). But, should a VLAN interface be used in the setup somewhere (`ip link add link ... name ... type vlan id ... protocol ...`), its VLAN protocol can't be changed later: this interface would have to be deleted and recreated to change the VLAN protocol. Once created, the protocol can't be changed. An attempt to change it (using `ip link set ... type vlan protocol ...` is silently accepted but has no effect.

Comment: Didn't work. It may be MySwitch that lacks a feature or is misconfigured somewhere. I will post the solution if I found it. I will try to test this on my system and if it works I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SAMPro You should use tcpdump (-e -n -l -v ...)  or an equivalent tool on every interface involved here: at least 6 running at once, to check at each step if what is captured is what should be here (eg: does the Cisco-to-MySwitch link really see 802.1Q and not non-VLAN? etc.)